# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, payment, 3d-secure

I am working on third party payment integration Adyen in Hybris , After a successful 3D Secure verification, the card issuer redirects the shopper to our website. In this case, I will receive an HTTP POST call to the URL that I specified in returnURl which in my case is `https://localhost:9002/test/en/EUR/payment/submitResponse` .

The HTTP POST call from the card issuer to our URL includes the following parameters:

1. MD – A payment session identifier returned by the card issuer.
2. PaRes – A payment authorisation response returned by the card issuer.

Request Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://test.test.com
Referer: https://test.test.com/hpp/3d/authenticate.shtml
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36
Form Data->
MD: SomeString
PaRes: SomeString
```

Controller Annotation :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment")
```

Method:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/submitResponse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> submitResponse(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
        responseMap.put("Key", "hello im submitted");
        return responseMap;
    }
```

I checked the headers of the POST request coming from Adyen ,and found Form Data :

```
md="SomeString"
Pares="someString"
```

However, I am getting following exception:

```
WARN  [hybrisHTTP34] [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

In browser console :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()
```

Comment: what is on your controller annotation?

Comment: @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment")

Comment: cant see what is missing...try a get... see what would be the resultat. usually when springs load you get a log wih all the mapping url

Comment: Yes, it works with GET but my requirement is to use POST

Comment: Did you check the URL that was called in access log? /hybris/log/tomcat/accessXXXX.log

Comment: Yes, it was a POST call to the URL , also response sent was a POST

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your response, I passed CSRF token to Adyen request and it started working.